# On click external link open first accordion

Tags: jquery

I have created two external links and two section containing accordion in each. When I click on Link it scroll to its particular section. I am trying to open its first accordion on Link click.

**https://jsfiddle.net/adampavlov/4s7dc09b/13/**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Add smooth scrolling to all links
$(".explore-card a").on('click', function(event) {
// Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
if (this.hash !== "") {
// Prevent default anchor click behavior
event.preventDefault();
// Store hash
var hash = this.hash;
// Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
// The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
$('html, body').animate({
scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
}, 800, function(){
// Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
window.location.hash = hash;
});
} // End if
});
});
```

I am trying to open its first accordion on external Link click.

Comment: Which part of the code is attempting to expand the accordion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding these attributes to the first link will do it:

```
data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#a1"
```

After adding it will look like this:

```
<a href="#Segment1" class="explore-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#a1">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r1vd3jgp/

Comment: You are most welcome. If it helps feel free to upvote the answer if you want.

Comment: Brother, I appreciate your work but this time I am not able to Upvote because it need minimum 15 reputation in my account, while I have only 3 reputation